# Lambda and proc generated

Tags: ruby, lambda

I read about Proc in ruby at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Proc.html

```
lambda(&lambda {}).lambda?   #=> true
proc(&lambda {}).lambda?     #=> true
Proc.new(&lambda {}).lambda? #=> true

lambda(&proc {}).lambda?     #=> false
proc(&proc {}).lambda?       #=> false
Proc.new(&proc {}).lambda?   #=> false
```

And I almost don't understand why all the results are they. If you have any idea. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

It says so right above the code you quoted:

> `lambda`, `proc` and `::new` preserve the tricks of a `Proc` object given by `&` argument.

In the first three examples, you create a `Proc` using `lambda {}`; thus it is a lambda. Wrapping it doesn't change it; `.lambda?` is `true`.

In the second three examples, you create a `Proc` using `proc {}`; thus it is not a lambda. Wrapping it doesn't change it; `.lambda?` is `false`.

Comment: So why wrapping a lambda/proc doesn't change it?

Comment: You will have to ask people who designed it.

Comment: Ok! Thank for your help